# Integer Surrogate Key?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I need something real simple, that for some reason I am unable to accomplish up to this point.

I have also been unable to Google the answer surprisingly. I need to number the entries in different tables uniquely. I am aware of AUTO INCREMENT in MySQL and that it will be involved. My situation would be as follows:

If I had a table like

Table EXAMPLE

```
   ID - INTEGER
   FIRST_NAME - VARCHAR(45)
   LAST_NAME - VARCHAR(45)
   PHONE - VARCHAR(45)
   CITY - VARCHAR(45)
   STATE - VARCHAR(45)
   ZIP - VARCHAR(45)
```

This would be the setup for the table where ID is an integer that is auto-incremented every time an entry is inserted into the table. The thing I need is that I do not want to have to account for this field when inserting data into the database. From my understanding this would be a surrogate key, that I can tell the database to automatically increment and I do not have to include it in the INSERT STATEMENT

So, instead of:

```
 INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (2,'JOHN','SMITH',333-333-3333,'NORTH POLE'....
```

I can leave out the first ID column and just write something like:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES ('JOHN','SMITH'.....etc)
```

Notice I wouldn't have to define the ID column...

I know this is a very common task to do, but for some reason I cant get to the bottom of it.

I am using MySQL, just to clarify.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES ('JOHN','SMITH'.....etc)
```

...will return a MySQL Error #1136, because the number of columns in the table do not match the number of columns specified in the `VALUES` clause.  So you have two options:

1. Use `NULL` to fill in the autoincrement column value.  IE:

   ```
   INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (NULL, 'JOHN','SMITH'.....etc)
   ```
2. Specify the list of columns for the table that values are being provided for.  IE:

   ```
   INSERT INTO EXAMPLE 
     (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE, CITY, STATE, ZIP)
   VALUES 
     ('JOHN','SMITH'.....etc)
   ```

Comment: for either of these examples, if I specify the ID column to AUTO INCREMENT, will it handle it correctly?

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum: Yes, if the ID column is set to be AUTOINCREMENT - use either example I provided.

Comment: I used your first option, it fit my needs the best, and I believe it would have the least refactoring. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

Make `ID` `auto_increment` as shown [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).  You don't have to provide the value for an `auto_increment` field when inserting a row, the DB will provide it for you.  Note that in this case you still have to use the `insert` syntax such that you provide  the names of the fields, and you'd just leave out the `ID` field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about mysql, but in SQL Server you would need to specify the fields you were inser'ing into in the insert (which you should do in all cases anyway as a best practice).

have you tried

```
insert into Example(field1, field2)
values ('John', 'Smith')
```

Comment: When you don't list the columns after the table, you are relying on the ordinal positions of the columns within the table.  This is never a good idea because your code can break unexpectedly.

Comment: Or worse, not appear to break (i.e. no error message) but put the data in the worng places. THis can go on for some time before someone notices and it's really hard to fix bad data that has been affected by something like this.